# How to make Material UI Typography without newline?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

The default `Typography` in Material UI moves the next tag-element on a new line. How to customize this component when the next  was on the same line?

I use [this](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/typography/) component.

Comment: what is "f.e."?

Comment: I mean for example

Comment: "For example" is actually shortened e.g. :)

Comment: ...naturally...

Comment: Related oatmeal: https://theoatmeal.com/comics/ie

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Set the `display` style of the component to anything other than `block`.

```html
<Typography style={{display: 'inline-block'}}>Left</Typography>
<Typography style={{display: 'inline-block'}}>Right</Typography>
```

Comment: this should be `style={{display: 'inline-block'}}`, you are missing the `' '`

Answer (score 65):

Rather than override the style, just apply the `inline` prop or `display` prop (depending on your version).

`Previous to 4`

```
<Typography inline>Left</Typography>
<Typography inline>Right</Typography>
```

`4.x`

```
<Typography display="inline">Left</Typography>
<Typography display="inline">Right</Typography>
```

https://material-ui.com/api/typography/

Comment: This worked for me, don't know why I didn't think of this sooner. Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

The reason **why** the next element goes to new line is because regular Typography transforms to the following code:

```
<p class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-body2 css-9emux6">
   <!-- Your code here -->
</p>
```

So, paragraph works the way it moves elements after it to the next line. With MUI version >= 4.x you can use attribute **"component"** like this:

```
<Typography variant="body2" component="span">
       <!-- Your code here -->
</Typography>
```

The code above will be transformed to:

```
<span class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-body2 css-9emux6">
   <!-- Your code here -->
</span>
```

So, as we all know **"span"** is an **"inline"** component and next element (if it is also **"inline"**) will not be moved to a new line.

Answer (score 7):

As of material 4 you can do this

```
<Typography display="inline">Left</Typography>
<Typography display="inline">Right</Typography>
```

Answer (score 3):

Typography uses "< p >< /p > as HTML tag. It will not be possible to keep long text in one line. Try to use < span > instead.

Updated 25/06/2019

With display="inline" should work.

Comment: I would say that using component={span} is still better option than forcing paragraph to be inline.

Answer (score 2):

To remove the newline in all `Typography` variants in **MUI v5**:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  typography: {
    allVariants: {
      '&': {
        display: 'inline',
      },
    },
  },
});
```

To set `inline` only in some variants:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  typography: {
    subtitle1: { display: 'inline' },
    subtitle2: { display: 'inline' },
    body1: { display: 'inline' },
    body2: { display: 'inline' },
    button: { '&': { display: 'inline' } }, // add '&' to increase CSS specificity
    caption: { '&': { display: 'inline' } },
    overline: { '&': { display: 'inline' } },
  },
});
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Answer (score 1):

I think the best,html, solution would be to make one a

tag and a child  tag ([reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp))

```
                <Typography  >
                    name:
                    <Typography component="span">
                        value
                    </Typography>

                </Typography>
```

Works for me with MUI 5